# Json.Net deserialize out of memory issue

Tags: c#, json.net, base64, out-of-memory

I got a Json, which contains among others a data field which stores a base64 encoded string.
This Json is serialized and send to a client.

On client side, the newtonsoft json.net deserializer is used to get back the Json.
However, if the data field becomes large (~ 400 MB), the deserializer will throw an out of memory exception: *Array Dimensions exceeded supported Range*.
I also see in Task-Manager, that memory consumption really grows fast.

Any ideas why this is? Is there a maximum size for json fields or something?

Code example (simplified):

```
HttpResponseMessage responseTemp = null;
responseTemp = client.PostAsJsonAsync(client.BaseAddress, message).Result;

string jsonContent = responseTemp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result;
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(jsonContent);
```

Result class:

```
public class Result
{

    public string Message { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think my problem is **not** the serializer, but just trying to handle such a huge string in memory. 
At the point where I read the string into memory, the memory consumption of the application explodes. Every operation on that string does the same. At the moment, I think I have to find a way to work with streams and stop reading the whole stuff into memory at once.

Comment: Can you share the code for the object that is being created by deserialization?

Comment: just added a small code snippet. Would already help if someone can confirm that such huge base64 strings are not a problem in general.

Comment: It would help to see the code for the 'result' type too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incremental JSON Parsing in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026508/incremental-json-parsing-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @DanielG Is it the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<result> that fails?

Comment: yes, that's the one that fails with OOM Exception. Just added the result class, which is really simple.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151125/deserializing-large-json-objects-from-web-service-out-of-memory

Comment: I already tried that, but doesn't make any difference. Exact same error. Just posted the string version to keep the code simple.

Comment: I also tried using the JsonTextReader directly. That also doesn't work. It will fail when it comes to JsonTextReader.Read on the huge field. And it throws the exact same error.

Comment: In c#, [an array can only hold `int.MaxValue` items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391672).  From the error message it sounds like Json.NET is trying to create an array larger than this.  What is the full `ToString()` output of the exception *including the traceback*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. You have a *single Base64 data field* inside your JSON response that is larger than ~400 MB.
2. You are loading the entire response into an intermediate string `jsonContent` that is even larger since it embeds the single data field.

Firstly, I assume you are using 64 bit.  If not, [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx).

Unfortunately, the first problem can only be ameliorated and not fixed because Json.NET's [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) does not have the ability to read a single string value in "chunks" in the same way as [`XmlReader.ReadValueChunk()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readvaluechunk?view=netframework-4.8).  It will always fully materialize each atomic string value.  But .Net 4.5 adds the following settings that may help:

1. [`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element).

   > This setting allows for arrays with up to [`int.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) entries even if that would cause the underlying memory buffer to be larger than 2 GB.  You will still be unable to read a *single JSON token* of more than 2^31 characters in length, however, since [`JsonTextReader`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs) buffers the full contents of each single token in a `private char[] _chars;` array, and, in .Net, [an array can only hold up to `int.MaxValue` items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391672).
2. [`GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode?view=netframework-4.5.1).

   This setting allows the [large object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953503) to be compacted and may reduce out-of-memory errors due to address space fragmentation.

The second problem, however, can be addressed by streaming deserialization, as shown in [this answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40462038/3744182) by [Dilip0165](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2318354/dilip0165); *[Efficient api calls with HttpClient and JSON.NET](https://johnthiriet.com/efficient-api-calls/)* by John Thiriet;  *[Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage)* by Newtonsoft; and *[Streaming with New .NET HttpClient and HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/streaming-with-newnet-httpclient-and-httpcompletionoption-responseheadersread)* by Tugberk Ugurlu.  Pulling together the information from these sources, your code should look something like:

```
Result result;
var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message); // Here we assume the request JSON is not too large
using (var requestContent = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress) { Content = requestContent })
using (var response = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result)
using (var responseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using (var textReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
        {
            result = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<Result>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: handle an unsuccessful response somehow, e.g. by throwing an exception
    }
}
```

Or, using `async/await`:

```
Result result;
var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message); // Here we assume the request JSON is not too large
using (var requestContent = new StringContent(requestJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress) { Content = requestContent })
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        using (var textReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
        {
            result = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<Result>(jsonReader);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: handle an unsuccessful response somehow, e.g. by throwing an exception
    }
}
```

My code above isn't fully tested, and [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpresponsemessage.issuccessstatuscode) and cancellation handling need to be implemented.  You may also need to set the timeout as shown [here](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/streaming-with-newnet-httpclient-and-httpcompletionoption-responseheadersread) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10547895).  Json.NET's `JsonSerializer` does not support async deserialization, making it a slightly awkward fit with the asynchronous programming model of `HttpClient`.

Finally, as an alternative to using Json.NET to read a huge Base64 chunk from a JSON file, you could use the reader returned by [`JsonReaderWriterFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory?view=netframework-4.8) which *does* support reading Base64 data in manageable chunks.  For details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56049862/3744182) to *[Parse huge OData JSON by streaming certain sections of the json to avoid LOH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56038495/3744182)* for an explanation of how stream through a huge JSON file using this reader, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30116082) to *[Read stream from XmlReader, base64 decode it and write result to file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30102571)* for how to decode Base64 data in chunks using [`XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsBase64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readelementcontentasbase64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: yeah, I'm on 64 bit. Setting gcAllowVeryLargeObjects helped. But however, since memory is increasing very fast, I will try to change the handling and avoid reading the stuff in to memory. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielG - If you decide to do the parsing manually, take a look at [Decode base64 filestream with FromBase64Transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121310/decode-base64-filestream-with-frombase64transform).  The 2nd answer shows how you can stream & decode base64 character data of any length.

Comment: What should be the solution for earlier versions of .NET 4.5?

Comment: @Fabiano - is your problem that the JSON response overall is huge, or that it contains a *single property* that is huge?  If the response is huge use streaming as shown in the other answer.  If a single property is huge then it's not obvious what to do.  Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @dbc, we have figured out here that the object to be deserialized has 30 MB, and the OutOfMemory exception is being raised. It is not a single property, but the whole object that is huge. We are thinking about zipping the string instead of deserializing it. And then, the other side can handle the unzip and the treatment for the rest.
Unless there is another good idea to deserialize huge objects with .NET 4.0 :)

Comment: @Fabiano - If the JSON is huge but the individual properties are not then 1) Be sure you are running in 64 bit; and 2) Stream directly as shown in the other answer.  30 MB isn't actually a huge amount of memory to allocate overall -- it's just a problem to allocate *contiguously*.  If streaming doesn't fix your problem you should ask another question and include a [mcve].

Answer (score 23):

To read large JSON string with use of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject will consume your lots of memory. So One of the ways to over come from this issue, you can create an instance of JsonSerializer as given below.

```
 using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
 {
          using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(r))
         {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                T lstObjects = serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }
}
```

Here **filePath** :- is your current Json file and
**T** :- is your Generic type object.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It presents a good practice instead of the answers that do not cure the problem but only try to minimize the risk. Thanks!

Comment: this solution solved a huge memory leak problem for me

Comment: His question is not about file path but for a string as json. Can you please extend your answer?

Comment: I am facing an issue where even with the use of a StreamReader to deserialize json data, it still getting the out of memory problem. Maybe this solution together with gcAllowVeryLargeObjects should do the trick.

Comment: @Fabiano Me too. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @pushkin To be frank with you, I don't remember exactly how this was solved. But the working solution today is that we are compressing the data before serializing and deserializing. If you deserialize a compressed data, you won't have this out of memory problem. After that, you can just uncompress it and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Huge base64 strings aren't a problem as such, .Net supports object sizes of around 2gb, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616739/why-is-the-max-size-of-byte-2-gb-57-b). 
Of course, that doesn't mean you can store 2gb of information in an object!

However, I get the feeling that it's the byte[] that's the problem.

If there's too many elements for a byte[] to contain, it doesn't matter if you stream the result or even read it from a file on your hard drive.

So, just for testing purposes, can you trying changing the type of that from byte[] to string or even perhaps a List? 
It's not elegant or event perhaps advisable, but it might point the way to a better solution.

**Edit:**

Another test case to try, instead of calling deserializeObject, try just saving that jsonContent string to a file, and see how big it is?

Also, why do you need it in memory? What sort of data is it?
It seems to me that if you've got to process this in memory then you're going to have a bad time - the size of the object is simply too large for the CLR.

Just had a little inspiration however, what about trying a different deserializer? Perhaps RestSharp or you can use `HttpClient.ReadAsAsync<T>`. It is possible that it's NewtonSoft itself that has a problem, especially if the size of the content is around 400mb.

Comment: Just switched to a pure string. Unfortunately it doesn't make any difference. I get the exact same errors. In Taskmanager I see that memory grows up to 3.5 GB within seconds.

Comment: That's a real shame... I just updated my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: ok thanks again. I don't need it in memory. It will be written to a database later. Unfortunately I need to handle it that way because of some ugly legacy code. I will try another serializer...that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the JSON result is an array, you can use this (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115672/989451). It helped me with avoid out of memory exceptions. This will read and deserialize each array item separately:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeSequenceFromJson<T>(TextReader readerStream)
{
    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(readerStream))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        // find start of array
        while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            reader.Read();
        }

        // deserialize each item until end of array
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray) break;
            var item = serializer.Deserialize<T>(reader);
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```